# draw circle with a point

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Im trying to make a UIView draw a circle with a point obviously i can get it to circle like so

```
view.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0f;
view.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

but I am wanting to make a point like so

[image]

this must be possible but I am unable to figure it out. may just be tired :/

The content will hold dynamic images or changing colors so designing an image isnt really possible as i need the contents of the view conform to the shape

Comment: if the content is going to hold dynamic images/shapes then you need to look at CAShapeLayers or drawRect.

Comment: Create a custom `UIView` class and implement the `drawRect:` method. Draw a circle and a triangle to get the shape you want.

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/bubblethingie. Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of ways to accomplish this. Here is an example. Just put this into your `drawRect:` method.

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Oval
UIBezierPath* ovalPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[UIColor.grayColor setFill];
[ovalPath fill];

// Rectangle
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 79, 50);
CGContextRotateCTM(context, -45 * M_PI / 180);

UIBezierPath* rectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25)];
[UIColor.grayColor setFill];
[rectanglePath fill];

CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

You may want to look into getting an app like [PaintCode](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/) to help you with stuff like this. It handles these sorts of drawings with ease and can help you learn how to create them yourself.